# Play2 Java Action Composition - how do I string together multiple actions?

Tags: java, filter, playframework, composition

I have this controller in play.

```
@With(SecuredAction.class)
public class Application extends Controller {
    public void hasSomeMethods(){ return ok("blah blah");}
}
```

And the annotation points to what is basically an interceptor for security concerns.

```
public class SecuredAction extends Action.Simple {

    @Override
    public F.Promise<Result> call(Http.Context context) throws Throwable {
        return delegate.call(context);
    }
}
```

How do I add a second action to the composition - say one called LoggedAction??
Annotating the SecuredAction with @With doesn't seem to work and @With only allows one class. Do I need to use custom annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@With` is defined as:

```
public @interface With {
    java.lang.Class<? extends play.mvc.Action<?>>[] value();
}
```

so something like this should work:

```
@With({SecuredAction.class, LoggedAction.class})
public class Application extends Controller {
    public Result hasSomeMethods(){ return ok("blah blah");}
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I figured it out - forgot to come back and close this. Realized I don't make arrays often :P